# Remove brackets and letters from string, regex

Tags: php

I have these strings returned in variable `$item_data`..

`180 - 190 (cm)`

`20 (litres)`

How do i remove `(cm)` or `(litres)` from the string and only allow numbers and the dash?

```
$item_data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]+/', '', $item_data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work :)

```
$item_data = preg_replace('/[^0-9-]+/', '', $item_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use also

```
$str="180 - 190 (cm)";
echo $result = preg_replace('/[^\d-]+/', '', $str);
```

output:180-190